# Implement search option/tool in website

Tags: php, search

I have to implement search option/tool in my website. Search tool should search contents only from my website like some category name or file name. I'm developing website in PHP. I have also referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314/how-do-i-implement-search-functionality-in-a-website) too. But I want some templates or
some demo like video lecture or blog which describes that how to develop.

In that link, there is option to describe all the data. But how? And I also want to develop in core PHP.

If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You.

Comment: providing outside resources is not the purpose of SO. read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The search should actually be handled by the database, such as mysql. After the running the search specific query, the data will be passed to php, were you may convert the retrieved data to the right markup

Comment: Ok.. Sorry.. But then please just help me by describing sequential steps to develop that tool.

Comment: @Fleuv .. I know that I need to use mysql database.. But I can't get idea about database structure for search, indexing data etc.. So please explain in some detail.

Comment: @Akshay Vaghasiya a simple search will just be a single dynamic query e.g: `select * from pages where title like '%search-value%';`

Comment: @Fleuv and what about category search?? If you know how to index data, then also explain be it too.

Comment: @Akshay Vaghasiya add another where: ...`title like '%foo%' and category = 'bar'`